# How to get the old value of a column after an UPDATE

Tags: cassandra

I m new to Cassandra..how to get 
the old value  of a column  after the updation took place. when we update a column in cassandra db?

Answer (score 4):

You read the column, before you update it.  There is no return value to an update call.

Answer (score 0):

Note that Cassandra has a "lousy" read/write mechanism (it will depend on the consistency level that you're using.) If you write an application, you should have the new value in your program, so you should use that value directly (make it available in some way.) My C++ implementation http://snapwebsites.org/project/libqtcassandra automatically does that for you (you actually have to clear the cache to make sure you re-read things from the database!)

The only other way is to re-read the value (as jbellis) mentioned. However, if you want to make 100% sure that you're reading back the latest value, you must use a consistency of FULL (read the latest from any one of the Cassandra nodes.) Not doing so may return an older value.

Comment: "lousy" a Freudian slip for "lossy"?